# PrimeNg autocomplete issue- onKeuUp doesn't fire on tab out

Tags: primeng

Can someone please suggest a solution for the following problem.
I'm using primeNg-8 autocomplete...
There are 6 ways user can open part search/get an exact match(Just an API Call) –

- Type in something tab out
- Type in something press enter
- Type in something then click somewhere else
- Select something from suggestion box with mouse click
- Select something from suggestion box with tab out
- Select something from suggestion box with enter key

All these scenarios we fixed in primeNG 5 version, seems with primeNg 8 the internal implementation has changed little bit with respect to how they show/hide the autocomplete suggestion box on DOM. Because of this one case is failing

Here is the exact scenario which fails-

Type in something suggestion box comes user just tabs out without selection anything, please note that if user types in something and press enter or click somewhere else this works.
If user types in something and immediately tabs out before suggestion box comes this also works.

-The problem is onKeyUp doesn't fire in tab out.